# What does 'connector.lookup.cache.max-rows' mean

Tags: apache-flink

When I define a mysql table as the dimonsion table, the definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE MyUserTable (
  ...
) WITH (
  'connector.type' = 'jdbc', -- required: specify this table type is jdbc
  
  'connector.url' = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flink-test', -- required: JDBC DB url
  
  'connector.table' = 'jdbc_table_name',  -- required: jdbc table name
  
  'connector.driver' = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', -- optional: the class name of the JDBC driver to use to connect to this URL. 
                                                -- If not set, it will automatically be derived from the URL.

  'connector.username' = 'name', -- optional: jdbc user name and password
  'connector.password' = 'password',
  'connector.lookup.cache.max-rows' = '5000', -- optional, max number of rows of lookup cache, over this value, the oldest rows will
                                              -- be eliminated. "cache.max-rows" and "cache.ttl" options must all be specified if any
                                              -- of them is specified. Cache is not enabled as default.
  'connector.lookup.cache.ttl' = '10s', -- optional, the max time to live for each rows in lookup cache, over this time, the oldest rows
                                        -- will be expired. "cache.max-rows" and "cache.ttl" options must all be specified if any of
                                        -- them is specified. Cache is not enabled as default.
  'connector.lookup.max-retries' = '3', -- optional, max retry times if lookup database failed
```

I have defined `connector.lookup.cache.max-rows = 5000` and `connector.lookup.cache.ttl = 10s`

If my mysql table has 10001 rows(more than `connector.lookup.cache.max-rows`), does it mean

1. The first 5000 rows in mysql table will be cached?
2. After 10s, these 5000 rows will be expired, and another 5000 rows in mysql table will be cached?

I don't think it behaves what I described above, so, what's the exact behavior if I have more rows(10001 here) than that has been specified with `connector.lookup.cache.max-rows`(500 here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way this works is that every time there is a cache miss, the connector will read [scan.fetch-size](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/#scan-fetch-size) rows from the database.

Rows are expired from the cache when their TTL expires, and the oldest rows are kicked out to make room for freshly fetched rows when the cache is full.

The [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/#lookup-cache) describe the lookup cache behavior in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @david-anderson for the helpful answer!